# Python: How to sort a list based on another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to order list1 based on the strings in list2. Any elements in list1 that don't correspond to list2 should be placed at the end of the correctly ordered list1.

For example:

```
list1 = ['Title1-Apples', 'Title1-Oranges', 'Title1-Pear', 'Title1-Bananas']
list2 = ['Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Pear']

list1_reordered_correctly= ['Title1-Bananas','Title1-Oranges','Title1-Pear','Title1-Apples']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
>>> def keyfun(word, wordorder):
...     try:
...         return wordorder.index(word)
...     except ValueError:
...         return len(wordorder)
... 
>>> sorted(list1, key=lambda x: keyfun(x.split('-')[1], list2))
['Title1-Bananas', 'Title1-Oranges', 'Title1-Pear', 'Title1-Apples']
```

To make it neater and more efficient (`index` has to traverse the list to find the right item), consider defining your word-order as a dictionary, i.e.:

```
>>> wordorder = dict(zip(list2, range(len(list2))))
>>> wordorder
{'Pear': 2, 'Bananas': 0, 'Oranges': 1}
>>> sorted(list1, key=lambda x: wordorder.get(x.split('-')[1], len(wordorder)))
['Title1-Bananas', 'Title1-Oranges', 'Title1-Pear', 'Title1-Apples']
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is conceptual rather than efficient.

```
st1dict = dict((t.split('-')[1],t) for t in st1) #keys->titles
list2titles = list(st1dict[k] for k in list2)    #ordered titles
extras = list(t for t in st1 if t not in list2titles)  #extra titles
print(list2titles+extras)  #the desired answer
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner.

```
sorted_list = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: list2.index(x.split('-')[1]) if x.split('-')[1] in list2 else len(list2) + 1)
```

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you are adding some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use code below to achieve desired sorting:

```
list1 = ['Title1-Apples', 'Title1-Oranges', 'Title1-Pear', 'Title1-Bananas']
list2 = ['Bananas', 'Pear']

# note: converting to set would improve performance of further look up
list2 = set(list2)

def convert_key(item):
    return int(not item.split('-')[1] in list2)



print sorted(list1, key=convert_key)
#  ['Title1-Pear', 'Title1-Bananas', 'Title1-Apples', 'Title1-Oranges']
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this would get you going on this.

```
l = ['Title1-Apples', 'Title1-Oranges', 'Title1-Pear', 'Title1-Bananas']
l2 = ['Bananas', 'Oranges', 'Pear']
l3 = []
for elem_sub in l2:
    for elem_super in l:
        if elem_sub in elem_super:
            l3.append(elem_super)

print(l3 + list(set(l)-set(l3)))
```